# Jaxb Marshalling Unmarshalling instead of Java Beans

Tags: java, architecture, jaxb, javabeans

I have a webservice orchestrator which invokes multiple webservices. For each webservice call I have to write lengthy mapping code before invoking the downstream service.

*EDIT: I have the wsdls for each of these services and currently I've generated the classes using jaxb. The responses each of these services are saved in a common object which is then passed on to the next service call where I have a transformer which picks the values from this common object and populate the downstream request DTO. The orchestration logic is performed in the business layer before deciding which webservice to invoke. At the most, the number of elements sent to any webservice is around 200. Some of these values are obtained from the incoming request, some of them are defaulted and some of them are values from other web service calls.*

*I want to reduce the amount of boilerplate null checks and get/set code in my mapping classes without adversely affecting current performance.*

Is Marshalling and UnMarshalling and using Jaxb and XML tools to read and write data a better way to approach this in my scenario?

In any case my web service invocation is a SOAP request. Is java beans just being used in the industry just because everyone else is using it?

If marshalling / unmarshalling with jaxb is not a viable alternative, are there better ways (in terms of performance and verbosity) to tackle this issue?

I tried JXPath and Mapstruct but writing the mapping code or overriding the Abstract factory is just as tedious with these two.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put technology on the first place. You design to requirements and constraints, not to the technology in first place.

So it is hard to give a specific advise without knowing your specific requirements and constraints. Do you have much business logic when orchestrating or is it just pass-through? What are the performance requirements? Other non-functional reqs? Are the services complicated? Are they known in advance? Are the schemas for the web services valid/good? Is the orchestration structure static or should it be possible to add new services dynamically? How much data passes through? Should it be built or can it be bought? Etc. etc.

These are just a few questions which came to my mind as I was typing. And depending on the answers I'd design it in very different ways, with different toolsets. From simple XSLT to full-fledged SOA stacks.

Concerning JAXB, a **disclaimer:** I am actually a big fan of JAXB, had very good experience with it over the years. I've solved mapping tasks (like you sketched) a couple of times with JAXB, for instance with [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or my own [Copyable](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Copyable+plugin) plugin and interfaces. But I cannot recommend it unless your requirements and constraints are clear.